# TextBox keypress event not fires inside Google map infowindow

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I tried to allow only valid characters on a TextBox inside a Google map infowindow. The 'keypress' event is not fires. Please help me to resolve this problem.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {

        var polylength=polygon.getPath().getArray().length;
        var lastarray=polygon.getPath().getAt(polylength-1);

            vertex=polygon.getPath().getArray();
        var contentString="<form id='myform'>Name:<input name='cname' id='cname' type='text' size='50'></input><br>Address<input name='addr' id='addr' type='text' size='50'></input><br><input type='button' value='submit' onclick='save();'></input></form>";
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString,
            });
        infowindow.setPosition(lastarray);
        infowindow.open(map);
    }); 

$('input').bind('keypress', function(event){
                 alert("pressed");
                var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$");
                var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
                if (!regex.test(key)) {
                   event.preventDefault();
                   return false;
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are `bind`ing event listener to `input` fields, the `input` fields are not created yet.You need to add [domready](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) event listener on `infowindow` , then `bind` the `keypress`listener:

```
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: contentString,
});
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow , 'domready', function(){
    $('#myform input').bind('keypress', function(event){
             alert("pressed");
            var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$");
            var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
            if (!regex.test(key)) {
               event.preventDefault();
               return false;
            }
    });
});
```